# SpringBoot-MySQL or ExpressJS-MongoDB which one is best for building rest API of online BookStore?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, reactjs, express, spring-boot

How are you all? I'm a beginner with the web programming. I am planning to develop my personal e-commerce Bookstore for myself. I've basic knowledge of ReactJS, ExpressJS, Spring MVC, MongoDB, and Mysql.   I've already done some basic project in ReactJS, Spring MVC-MySQL and Express-MongoDB like Personal Diary, Cost management system, School management system etc.  My future plan is to build a native mobile app for this Bookstore. I am a little bit confused to select the language and framework. I've some question and need experts opinion and suggestion like you.

1. ReactJS or NextJS(Server Side Rendering), which one will best for the frontend of this Bookstore?
2. Do I have any possibility to face any problem in SEO in the SPA?
3. Which Framework and Database will best for building the backend for better performance and lower hosting cost?
4. By using that backend service, can I use the same API endpoint to build a native app?
5. Any alternative technology to develop the bookstore?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Hey there, welcome to stackoverflow. I'm sorry, but I think your question is off-topic. stackoverflow is for programming problems. General advice/recommendations are off topic. Check "What topics can I ask about here": https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score -1, accepted):

-ReactJS has a vibrant and big community, so you would find plenty of support
-As far as i understand type of language for the front-end or SPA's shouldn't affect your SEO
-Java is rock solid, battle tested whereas NodeJs is new and a lot of experiments still going around it. Although it is claimed to be faster and easier to work with.
-Cost ? the cheapest would be PHP Apache shared hosting. Java and or JavaScript will both cost almost the same on platforms like heroku or digital ocean.
-Yes you should be able to build native apps using the same endpoints.
-With what you know do not look for alternate technologies. (What you have is more than enough)
-Moral of the story - If you are alone doing everything, JavaScript can save you a lot of time and effort. (Building web-apps, hybrid mobiles apps and server side APIs, all using JavaScript), however if you choose Java for server side, that knowledge may help you build a native android app and then you will need to learn Swift for a native IOS app and JavaScript anyway for web apps.
Everything boils down to what you are doing and how you are doing it.
All the best!